# Regular expression for htaccess URL redirect

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect all files in a particular directory in my web server.

I am trying regular expressions such as

```
Redirect /data/january\/([a-zA-Z0-9]*).([a-zA-Z]*)  http://www.mysite.com/sample
```

The expression `/([a-zA-Z0-9]*).([a-zA-Z]*)` is trying to find expressions such as **dat35262.pdf**.

But its not working. Can you help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`RedirectMatch`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch), [`Redirect`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) does not handle regexp. Try :

```
RedirectMatch /data/january\/([a-zA-Z0-9]*)\.([a-zA-Z]*)$ http://www.mysite.com/sample
```